# Cannot create plots in Jupyter using Octave

Tags: jupyter, octave

I'm attempting to get Octave working in Jupyter and while I can execute basic math, I cannot get plots to work. Regardless of what type of graphics library I try to use, I get an error similar to this:

```
error: feval: function '__init_gnuplot__' not found
error: called from
    graphics_toolkit at line 98 column 5
```

Here's the code that faileds:

```
register_graphics_toolkit('gnuplot');
available_graphics_toolkits()
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");
```

I did some investigation and my best guess is that it looks like it's looking for a file called __init_gnuplot__.cc, based on the fact I found a file with a similar name but ends with '-tst'. However, that file doesn't exist and grepping the entire file structure under the octave directory doesn't find any instances of the function in the error.

Has Anaconda removed that functionality? Does anyone know where that '__init_gnuplot__' function is supposed to be located? Or, better yet, does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Even without specifying anything about the graphic toolkit, you cannot plot anything?

Comment: Nope. If I didn't add the first two lines in the code, I got different errors. What you see is as far as I managed to get.

Comment: I mean: none of the 3 lines.

Comment: Sorry. I just tried it to confirm, but I get the following error: error: no graphics toolkits are available!

Comment: OK... I can't help further, as I'm not using Jupyter. The classical Octave has a default graphic toolkit, without the need to specify one.